# Add parameter to M Query in Power BI ODATA soruce

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerquery

I am querying DEVOPS to create reports from the source data in POWER BI. I can do this no problem. I'd like to be able to restrict the data that is collected from the ODATA feed by date(CreatedDate). This is to minimise the amount of churn client side.

I can manually enter a date for CreatedDate ge [date] - this works fine.
I want to use a parameter instead called "ReportingDateFrom" as there are a few projects I want to query and collate without editing each query individually.

I've tried many different combinations of the below. I'm currently experiencing error as below.

What am I doing wrong?

> Error

```
    Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Date and Text.
Details:
    Operator=&
    Left=01/12/2022
    Right=' and State ne 'Removed' and State eq 'Closed'
```

> Example Code

```
    let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/zzz/xxx/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems?"
    &"$filter=(WorkItemType eq 'User Story' or WorkItemType eq 'Bug' or WorkItemType eq 'Spike' or WorkItemType eq 'Show and tell') and CreatedDate ge '" , DateTime.Date(ReportingDateFrom) & "' and State ne 'Removed' and State eq 'Closed' "
    &" and Descendants/any()"
    &"& $select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,Custom_CostCode,ChangedOn,Children"
    &"& $expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName),Iteration($select=IterationPath,StartDate,EndDate),ChangedOn($select=Date),Children($select=WorkItemId,Title,WorkItemType,State,CompletedWork;$expand=AssignedTo($select=UserName)),"
    &"Descendants("

    &"$apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task' or WorkItemType eq 'Defect')"
    
    &"/aggregate(CompletedWork with sum as CompletedWork)"

    &")",

    null, [Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4]),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(Source, {{"AssignedTo", "Unassigned"}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

[image: Showing valid parameter is referenced]

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your date to text before concatenating. Something like:

```
Text.From( DateTime.Date(ReportingDateFrom))
```